# 2px difference between button and container element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the display setting "table" to create a ul navbar with li containing evenly sized buttons. I set a box shadow on the ul to avoid 1px gaps in the shadow between buttons. Unfortunately it appears that the buttons are rendering 2px smaller than their containing li elements. This results in a gap between the shadow and the button.

[image: edge]

Any ideas on how to resolve? Previously, I had been using display:inline but I ran into the same issue. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfvq9/

CSS:

```
#navbar ul {
  top: 1%;
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0 2% 0 2%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #888888;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#navbar li {
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top:1px solid #696969;
  border-bottom:1px solid #696969;
  border-right:1px solid #696969;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

Pretty HTML: (actual HTML has no spacing to avoid 1px gaps)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix it:

```
#navbar button {
    margin: 2px 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfvq9/1/

Comment: Yep! Any idea why the button is shifted / doesn't take up the entire space?

Comment: Yeah, the borders are behaving weirdly (actually, normal behaviour for the CSS, but weird for humans) :)  Try setting border to 0 and you'll see. You need to compensate for them because they do not count towards the overall box size because of the display/position settings you set.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the quick response!